# Python: Add value into list inside dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to add a value into `weekdays:[0]` from a variable called `dow`.

```
create_data = {"startDateTime":"2015-02-23T09:05:00-0600","endDateTime":"2015-02-23T10:05:00-0600","accessories":[],"customAttributes":[{"attributeId":"3","attributeValue":""},{"attributeId":"5","attributeValue":"Yes"}],"description":"Placeholder     Description","invitees":[],"participants":[],"recurrenceRule":[{"type":"weekly","interval":2,"weekdays":[0],"repeatTerminationDate":"2015-05-24T09:50:00-0600"}],"resourceId":"15","resources":["15"],"title":"","userId":"26","startReminder":"","endReminder":""}
```

I'm getting confused between adding into a dictionary and a list.

Tried the following but it churns out the error below;

```
create_data['recurrenceRule']['weekdays'] = dow
```

Below is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 51, in <module>
    create_data['recurrenceRule']['weekdays'] = dow
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

How do I access that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_data` is a dictionary, `recurrenceRule` being one of its keys. Then, its value is a list:

```
>>> create_data['recurrenceRule']
[{'repeatTerminationDate': '2015-05-24T09:50:00-0600', 'interval': 2, 'type': 'weekly', 'weekdays': 2}]
```

So to change `weekdays` you firstly have to access to the first element in the list:

```
create_data['recurrenceRule'][0]['weekdays']=dow
                             ^^^
```

That's why you get this error:

```
create_data['recurrenceRule']['weekdays']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Because you are trying to access to the index (0, 1, 2...) of a list with a string.

Answer (score 1):

As value of `create_data['recurrenceRule']` is list and list contains dictionary as item. So We have to get item from the list i.e. dictionary and add `weekdays` key in it.

```
create_data['recurrenceRule'][0]['weekdays'] = dow
```